# Receiving message multiple time for same event Server sent event

Tags: angular, typescript, server-sent-events, eventsource, openhab

I am working on a Web app to control some light using openHab API and using SSE but when the light goes on I received 3 message at the same time

one with the value 100
and the two other same message with the actual value of the light (ex 45)
the value correspond to the % of the brightness of the light

```
eventSource.onmessage = (event: any) => {
      this.val = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data).payload).value;
      console.log("new val " + this.val);
      slid.value = this.val;
      if(this.val >= 1){
        this.light = true;
        button.checked= true;
      }
      else{
        this.light = false;
        button.checked = false;
      }
    };
```

the problem with that is that my progressbar that show where the light is goes to 100% then descend to the value it should and I would like to avoid that is there any thing to prevent the message or to update the value only for the last message received ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume this is a bug on the server-side, or a network problem, you could workaround it by adding a 0.1s wait before taking any action. Then if three messages arrive at the same time, only the 3rd will trigger any UI changes. Roughly like this (untested code, and the `this.light` in `changeUI()` will definitely need sorting out):

```
var timer = null;

eventSource.onmessage = (event: any) => {
      this.val = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data).payload).value;
      console.log("new val " + this.val);
      if(timer)clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(changeUI, 100, this.val);
      };

function changeUI(val){
    if(timer){clearTimeout(timer);timer=null;}   //Redundant but harmless
    slid.value = val;
    if(val >= 1){
        this.light = true;
        button.checked= true;
      }
    else{
        this.light = false;
        button.checked = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is a horrible idea, not only will it skip legit messages, it will also allow more duplicates to slip through after 100ms - if there are many more duplicates. The behavior we're trying to patch here seems like a legit bug, in Chrome it repeats the messages exponentially after every reconnect; so reaching 1mil duplicates will only take a few minutes, depending how long the server takes to close the connection.

Comment: @argon Are you saying this is a known Chrome bug? Can you link to the bug report? (I remain suspicious, as the way the OP described it, it sounds much more likely to be a bug on the sender side.)
(BTW, the 100ms was just for example: it simply has to be the difference between the first and third message - in fact, as the 3rd is just a duplicate of the 2nd, the difference between 1st (the buggy value) and the 2nd (correct value) is sufficient.)

Comment: I've not found any bug reports that describe this exactly; however, as mentioned: "it *seems*" to be a bug indeed as I've tested this and can confirm that it is not the server that sends duplicate messages. I've dumped the output buffer to a text-file exactly as it is sent to the client, shows up perfect in the file. .. and yes i've cleaned the output buffer entirely before buffering.

Comment: your idea seems logical, however, it may be a good idea to hash the message together with the message time-stamp (including milliseconds) and test each event's message against a register of messages already received - within specified (short) time period. Even though this is a rather nasty hack; it could be "safer" than simply skipping through, because, different browsers handle the [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) API differently.

Comment: @argon Are you also using OpenHAB, and seeing the exact same behaviour? Or another SSE setup, where you see duplicates (in which case how about starting a new question)? The key feature of the OP's problem was not the duplicates: it was that it sent a bogus "100" value, before sending the correct "45" value.

Comment: that's a great idea, however I am rather allergic to asking questions or providing answers on StackOverflow by now, doesn't matter how well you Markdown-format your message, and does not matter if there is no duplicate out there, you get voted down by idiots with high scores and no life; so, by all means, start a new question about it, let me know here and I'll upvote your question and provide any in depth details. Lastly: the setup i'm using for SSE is pure old fashioned home grown vanilla JS and PHP7.